# /usr/bin Permission change OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, permission

I am trying to set up Java on Xcode and it needs to access /usr/bin/java at some point. But I cannot get hold of this folder and I get this message: The folder “java” can’t be opened because you don’t have permission to see its contents.

Even when I try to reach the permission through Get Info the system does not open the folder because of the same restriction.

I think it is possible to change the permission through Terminal but I am afraid to blow up something on my Mac. How can I change the permission safely?

Answer (score 0):

*/usr/bin/java* is no valid folder in any installation or version of Java (I know of).

Instead the file */usr/bin/java* is a symlink to */System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java* installed by the default Apple Java installer (v1.6.x).

The Oracle Java installer (either JDK/SDK or JRE) is installed to /Library/Java.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: Answer below relevent to /**usr/bin** after Apple implemented SIP (10.11 El Cap). Many thanks to @klanomath for input-

***Specifically answering your question*** about wishing to change perms on on ***/usr/bin*** as you wish to do, this is a non-starter due to (SIP) protections.  Review output of `ls -alO /usr/bin/java` below and note the word ***restricted***:

```
terrencehoulahan$ ls -alO /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted 74 28 Oct 22:02 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but: 1. the OP's system is/was 10.9 > **no SIP**! 2. The question (*/usr/bin Permission change*) is misleading (something like a xy-problem).

Comment: OK, wasn't in the question but from the date I guess you're getting the 10.9.  Will update my answer to include your feedback which I accept is valid.

Comment: I can't see who downvoted nor do I know what the person thought when doing so. But as the question was "How can I change the permission safely?" it might be due to the fact that your post neither answers the question nor offers an alternative approach to solve the problem the OP has. OTOH the question is >4 years old, so maybe the problem isn't all that important anymore.

Comment: @F1Linux "Amin R. Nov 18 '15 at 11:57": It is OSX 10.9 and Java is already installed (a comment of the OP before I even answered the question).

Comment: Ahh, he mentioned 10.9, but in a comment, not the body.

Comment: To be fair, the question is rather low-quality, mixes a few partially understood concepts and reads like an XY problem (user asks about changing permissions but actually is looking for how to include Java in Xcode). It should have been put on hold already in 2015, I just did it now.

Comment: @nohillside I updated the subject and meta tags to ensure no further ambiguity that lead to these confusions.  I only answered as there was no accepted answer, but yes, had I seen the date as klanomath pointed out, I would have saw the SIP thingy.

Comment: It's not even a SIP thing. By default `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink to the Java binary itself, not a folder, so if the OP tried to "open" things already got strange. There are some (now deleted) comments beneath the question trying to get more information from the OP but the required clarification was never provided.

Comment: @nohillside klanomath pointed out that SIP wasn't even operative 4 years ago when the question was posted.  So yeah, I referring to something that didn't happen until two releases later. As Homer Simpson would say, "D'Oh!"...